# Screenshot Apps for iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I was wondering if there are any good recommendations on apps that takes screenshots of the iPhone simulator. I've tried apps like iPhone screenshot cropper but I'm looking for something that will allow me to make larger images. For example large enough to put on a poster. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**Update**: *I think that my answer is not optimal anymore, thanks to [this other answer from Gurpartap Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8226262/289501) (where <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> directly saves the image to your desktop). I'm not sure from which version of the iOS Simulator is this possible, but it's better and faster!*

You can also try <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while in the iOS simulator. Then open Preview or an image editing program and try <kbd>cmd+N</kbd> (the image is in the clipboard).

Edit: According to apple's new guidelines we need to provide high resolution screenshots. For that go to Simulator->Hardware->Device->iphone(Retina). You will be able capture images in 640 × 960 using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> .

Comment: This is the correct answer.  No need for third party apps.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a secret shortcut? Because I could not find where is the button that do this.

Comment: Currently I have the 5.0 version of the iOS Simulator, and you can go to "Edit" -> "Copy Screen" if you don't want to use the shortcut.

Comment: that is work fine with IOS 5 simulator.

Comment: cmd + s just worked for me.

Answer (score 67):

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in Simulator and the screenshot will appear on your Desktop (or wherever they go for you).

Answer (score 14):

I use [iOS Simulator Cropper](http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/), it's the best application, you can even select the screenshot type that you want, if it's for the App Store, Market...
[image: Example]

Comment: No longer necessary to use 3rd Party tools. See highest rated answer (i.e. the functionality is now built into Simulator)

Comment: is there same kind application for windows instead MAC?

Answer (score 13):

For Those searching for options for Screen capture **960x640** / Higher (for 4-inch display). Go to simulater->Hardware->device change it to **iphone(Retina-3.5 inch)** or **iphone(Retina-4 inch)**. And press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. Check Your **Desktop**. You got a screenshot of size 960x640 at your desktop.

Comment: apple details the devices and the dimensions they screenshot at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925. so for the 6.5" screen you can use `iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR` and for 5.5" use `iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus`.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use Command-shift-4?  [Taking Screenshots in Mac OS X](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X)

No matter what you grab it with you still only get the resolution of the 320 x 480 pixels.

Comment: Exactly so  its useless advice.

Comment: It probably wasn't the case back in 2009 but `Cmd+S` gets you full size shots even if you're viewing the simulator at 50% scale.

Answer (score 6):

**(cmd + shift + 4)**

=> then you can select the area you want, screen shot will store in your desktop.

**(cmd + shift + 4) then a space**

=> will take the screen shot of the currently focussed window and save it in your desktop.

**(cmd + s)**

=>Open your simulator and Press cmd+s or goto file=> save screen shot will save the screen shot of the simulator to the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you're still going to be limited to the native resolution of the iPhone (320x480), no matter what you use.  To use something like this for print, which is generally around 300dpi, your options aren't great, i.e. resizing in Photoshop...

Comment: This is not true... You can take screenshot of 960x640.

Comment: how? Every technique is only 320 that I have  tried

Answer (score 1):

I also use Snagit not only for capturing the iPhone Simulator screenshots and many other screen capturing as well. Their Mac version is not nearly as feature-rich as their Windows version. I hope TechSmith keeps on improving the Mac version.

Answer (score 1):

(cmd + shift + 4) then a space

=> will take the screen shot of the currently focussed window and save it in your desktop.

My bet is on this.. It gives a 3D look to the captured screen shot..
Also the camera which pops up when hit the above said combination is awesome. its like a SLR camera :)
Try it out and know for urself.. Cmd + Shift + 4+ Space.

Comment: (cmd + shift + 4) works but it wont work for uploading screenshots into iTunes Connect. Cmd+S is working for there.

Comment: OP never asked for uploading the screen shot for iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

You take the screenshots at the iPhone's resolution, and then you use [interpolation](http://innovativesolution.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/interpolation-resizing-of-a-bitmap-image/) to upscale your images. [Many programs](http://www.americaswonderlands.com/digital_photo_interpolation.htm) allow you to do that, but I agree with n3wtz that Photoshop is one of the best. I personally used it with remarkably good results.

Answer (score 0):

just use 'copy screen' in iphone simulator. go to your image editor of choice, paste, done. easy as that. (if you don't find it in the menu, search help)

Answer (score -1):

In terms of actually capturing the image itself from the simulator, you could do worse than Grab, which comes with OS X.

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE - Skitch has been purchased by [Evernote](http://evernote.com/).  Still pretty much the same, just an FYI.

I've deleted my recommendation for Skitch.  Since Evernote bought it, usability has gone way downhill.  It will still let you take a screenshot of the iOS simulator if that's what you're after, but it's not the tool it once was.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relevant to the question.. can we take an iOS screenshot with Skitch?

Comment: @Santthosh - Um... yes, you can.  He asked about how to take screenshots of the iphone simulator.  Either you aren't familiar with what Skitch does, or didn't read the question.  Either way a down-vote is inappropriate.