# Can I use iOS Simulator to make screenshots for App Store?

Tags: xcode, app-store, ios-simulator

I'd like to submit an iPhone+iPad app to Apple App Store.

According to [requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2), at least two screenshots are required:

1242 x 2208: for iPhone 
2048 x 2732: for iPad.

`iOS Simulator` allows to set Device type to iPhone 6 Plus (5.5 inch) and iPad pro (12.9 inch).

Does iTunes Connect accept screenshots made on `Simulator`? 
(Or do I have to buy an iPhone and iPad to make screenshots.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screenshot Apps for iPhone simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751783/screenshot-apps-for-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can submit with screenshots taken in the Simulator.

I recommend testing on a physical device though. You can use Test Flight with external testers who already own a device if you don't want or can't get your own.